# how to show the memory space layout of linux kernel by some command?

Tags: linux-kernel

I want to find some tools which can show the kernel memory space layout in Ubuntu.
I use the follow command :

```
root@esdk-executor:/# cat /proc/kallsyms | grep use_mm
ffffffff811bc390 T use_mm
ffffffff811bc440 T unuse_mm
ffffffff811e2130 t unuse_mm
ffffffff81db1360 R __ksymtab_unuse_mm
ffffffff81db1d50 R __ksymtab_use_mm
ffffffff81dc2f60 r __kcrctab_unuse_mm
ffffffff81dc3458 r __kcrctab_use_mm
ffffffff81dcae5e r __kstrtab_unuse_mm
ffffffff81dcae67 r __kstrtab_use_mm
=====================================================
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I haven't tried, but you can use memory dump analyzers (e.g. gdb) with `/proc/kcore`.